# What is the difference between a directory and a file with no extension?

Tags: file, operating-system, directory, file-extension

On nearly all types of computers (if not all), folders have no extension. So I was wondering, what is the difference between a directory and a file with no extension? Don't they have the same name?

Comment: A Directory can has more dir or files, while file can't.

Comment: which operating system you are using , by the way @think123 ?

Comment: Directories are file with list of childs in metadata in tabular form but its content section is 0, this gives it zero size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have a directory and a file of the same name (regardless of extension), just like you cannot have two files of the same name.

A directory is just a file, too.

The difference is that a directory can contain other files. It does not matter how it is called, it can have an extension (or two). What makes it a directory is that it was created as such.

Answer (score 1):

directory is  a collection of a the folders and files.
in the linux based system directories will be in blue colour and has the permissions stsrting with like --rwx-r--rwx and directories permisions start from the drwx--rwx for the owner and group and nothing guys do not need to recognize the directories and file.

Comment: Thank you, this is the only answer with a technical detail ('d').

Answer (score 0):

## Directory:

Directory is a collection of files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

difference between directory and File : A file is any kind of computer document and a directory is a computer document folder or filing cabinet.